# Как поменять URL для ресурсов указанных в JSF

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf

Сейчас когда я пишу подобное в JSF:

`<h:outputScript library="js" name="someScript.js" target="head" />`

На выходе получаю такой html

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/myCompany/faces/javax.faces.resource/someScript.js?ln=js"></script>`

Как сделать чтобы там был не относительный а полный путь? Например такой:

`<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://myAnotherSite.com/myCompany/faces/javax.faces.resource/someScript.js?ln=js"></script>`

Суть в том, что я хочу перенести всю статику на другой домен, поэтому относительный путь работать не будет. Должна же быть возможность переопределять поведение jsf, чтобы прибавлять к URL не /myCompany/faces/javax.faces.resource как сейчас работает по дефолту а свой другой адрес. А фильтровать например по .js или по library="js"

Comment: Как раз в текущем виде перенос пройдёт без сучка, без задоринки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  что значит пройдет? я хочу получать статику с другого домена, который сегодня может быть один завтра другой.  Т.е. например я храню url в бд или в пропертях и этот кусок должен использоваться вместо текущего домена, который сейчас работает по дефолту.

Comment: Извините, не правильно понял. Я почему-то решил, что разговор о переносе всего проекта. Для подключения статики с другого сервера придётся использовать обычные html-теги `<link>` и `<sсript>`.

Comment: Этого я больше всего боялся, у меня сотни таких ссылок в jsf файлах, я надеюсь найти где под капотом это работает чтобы исправить в одном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается просто, стандартными средствами JSF. На странице меняем `h:outputScript` на `script type="text/javascript"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{configurationController.scriptsServerAddress}/scripts/someScript.js"/>
```

Пример (заглушка) серверного компонента:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationController {

public String getScriptsServerAddress() {
    //вместо константы должна быть логика извлечения из БД либо файла .properties
    return "https://myAnotherSite.com";
  }
}
```

Если требуется возможность смены адреса сервера статики без перезапуска основного сервера, то область видимости компонента `ConfigurationController` следует заменить на другую, короткоживущую (SessionScoped, RequestScoped), либо продумать механизмы кеширования данных и очистки кеша.

В сгенерированном HTML получится так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myAnotherSite.com/scripts/someScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Этот способ мне известен, но он не решит основную проблему. Мне придется перелопатить все JSF файлы чтобы вставить #{configurationController.scriptsServerAddress}, я же хотел решить все менее трудоемко. В итоге использовал ResourceHandlerImpl, правда он пока не все ловит.